# json.net, JsonReaderException: After parsing a value an unexpected character was encountered

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

I am trying to deserialize a `JSON` `array` using `Newtonsoft JSON`. However, using the `string` received from the server, I am getting the following error:

```
Newtonsoft JSON, JsonReaderException: After parsing a value an unexpected character was encountered
```

If I hardcode the `string` in the deserialization, it is working just fine.

Here is the raw `JSON`. Received from server is identical to the hardcoded string when printing to console.

```
{"id":15,"username":"patrick"}
```

And the code deserializing it

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(jsonstring);
```

I suspect it has something to do with encoding.

What am I doing wrong?

---

*User class by request*

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptOut)]
public class User{


        [JsonProperty]
        private int id;
        [JsonProperty]
        private string username;

        public User (int setId, string setName){
                id = setId;
                username = setName;
        }


        public string GetUsername(){
                return username;
        }

}
```

Comment: Can you add the `User` class?

Comment: I can, but as mentioned, when using hardcoded `JSON` it executes fine.

Comment: I know, it's just better to get a full picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, what string you are trying to deserialize? I used the following code and didn't get any problems:

```
public static void Main()
{
      const string jsonString = "{ \"id\":15, \"username\":\"patrick\" }";
      User u = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(jsonString);
}
```